# How can I get minimum number by Recursion in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, netbeans

I have something error in my java code.. I'm trying to find the minimum number by recursion.. My error in last index.. I noted if the minimum number in last index I get error message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8". otherwise, if the minimum number isn't in last index, it return the first minimum number found in the array and never check other values.

This is my code:

```
  public static int minimumElement(int [] nums,int i){      
    if (i < nums.length && nums[i] < nums[i+1] )
        return nums[i];
    else
        return minimumElement(nums, i=i+1);
  }
```

Outputs

[image of first minimum number found in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giu0J.png)

[image of minimum number in last index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLtR2.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601232/finding-the-minimum-of-an-array-using-recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i < nums.length && nums[i] < nums[i+1] )
    return nums[i];
```

Let's say `nums.length = 20` and `i = 19`. Then `nums[19 + 1]` will be 21st element inside `nums` which can't exist in the array, hence you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
 //int mini = nums[0];  "I wrote it in main"
 public static int minimumElement(int [] nums,int mini, int i){
    if (i >= nums.length-1)
        return mini;
    if (mini > nums[i+1] )
        mini = nums[i+1];
    return minimumElement(nums, mini, i=i+1);
}
```